# Games on betting from a set

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory

Two players each chooses a number from the set $\{1,2,4\}$ and correspondingly bets an amount of \$$1$, \$$2$, or \$$4$. There is no collaboration between players.

Rules:

$1.$ If the two chosen numbers are identical, then the amounts are returned to each player.

$2.$ If the two numbers differ by $1$, the first player receives the whole amount.

$3.$ If the numbers have difference greater than $1$, then the second player receives the whole amount.

Problem:

Show that the equilibria can be found by the following LP:
\begin{equation}
\text{ minimize } \quad x_1 +x_2+x_3 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}   \text{subject to } \end{equation}
\begin{eqnarray}
5x_1 + 6x_2 + x_3 & \geq & 1 \\
7x_1 + 5x_2 + x_3 & \geq & 1 \\
4x_1 + 3x_2 + 5 x_3 & \geq & 1\\
x_1, x_2, x_3 & \geq & 0.
\end{eqnarray}

Remark:

I know how to transform from the game problem to an LP, however the payoff matrix I obtained for the row player (first player) is 
\begin{equation}
P= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 3 & 0 \\
3 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4 \end{array} \right), 
\end{equation}
which is totally different from the coefficients in the LP. Any ideas??? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you subtract the amount the player bet from each line to get the net outcome?  That gives $$\begin{equation}
P= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -2 \\
-4 & -4 & 0 \end{array} \right), 
\end{equation}$$ and makes the game zero-sum.

Comment: ahright, the notion of "payoff" is ambiguous in this question. But still, this payoff matrix is nowhere close to the coefficients of the LP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients in the LP are shifted by $+5$ from the coefficients of the correct payoff matrix that is given in the comments.

If you express the constraints as $$A^ty\ge 1$$ then observe that $$A=P+5\cdot\mathbb 1_{3\times 3}$$ where the correct payoff matrix $P$ is given in the comments and $1_{3\times3}$ denotes the matrix with all it's elements equal to 1. Now use that if $A$ is such that $a_{ij}=p_{ij}+c$ then $$\operatorname{val}(A)=\operatorname{val}(P)+c$$ and that a strategy is optimal in the game with payoff matrix $A$ iff this strategy is optimal in the game with payoff matrix $P$ to conclude that the given LP indeed gives you the optimal solution.

Comment: Is this indirect method of using LP to find an equilibrium a good one? Are other algorithms, such as Lemke-Howson algorithm better?

Comment: @Richard You do not need Lemke Howson for zero sum games. Now solving an LP with simplex does not guarantee polynomial time to find the equilibrium. For small problems (like the ones that come up in a course) solving the LP is never the best way to go. Finding equalizing strategies (after eventually of deletion of dominated strategies (even weakly dominated in zero sum games)) is the simplest way. For bimatrix games Lemke - Howson is ok, but I am not completely aware of all possible algorithms so I cannot tell you exactly. There is also a very nice online solver...

Comment: @Richard 2 things that I forgot to mention. In order to play the LP method you need (1) a zero-sum game (that is why it could not work with your matrix) and (2) the payoff matrix has to have positive entries! (that is why he shifted with +5. +4 would also be ok). He did not do that to confuse you, it was necessary

Comment: Yes, I realised that eventually.